# Why is it true that $NP \ne coNP \implies X = \emptyset$?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

Let the  class of languages $$X = \{ L \ | \ L\in NPC \land L\in coNPC\}$$

Why is it true that $NP \ne coNP \implies X = \emptyset$?

Comment: because every $L$ can be reduced to an NPC (/coNPC) language. Thus if there one $L$ in the intersection, all can be reduced to both NP and coNP and they will be equal.

Comment: Side question: does it really help you to ask so many questions? I mean, the fun in this topic is ponder on these questions. Mind it may take 1-4 hours to solve each, but it would be very fulfilling to do that yourself. I'm not saying you shouldn't use this site to get idea, but i'm just suggesting to put enough thought (~2-3 hours!) in each question before --- this is the fun part!! (at least, this was the fun part for me, when I was studying this material). If you don't think so, I'd be happy to discuss it in the [chat].

Comment: @RanG. Congratulations for making it to 10K rep!

Comment: @RanG., When you say "every $L$", do you mean every $L\in NP \cup coNP$?

Comment: And for the side note, I guess it's the fear to handle a question and fail.. :/

Comment: I mean if $L \in NPC \cap coNPC$  then any $L'\in NP \cup coNP$ by definition (of "complete") satisfies $L' \le_p L$. (sorry, wrote the comment very fast and it has a few errors).

Comment: as for the side note: Yes, you will fail sometimes. So what? only those who don't do, never fail.  PS. to ask a question after you have exhausted your thoughts and failed, is WAY MORE powerful towards your understanding. Try it, and see if I'm wrong.

Comment: @RickDecker thanks. I hope to see more users above 10k, as (i believe) this is crucial for graduating the site!

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  We expect you to make a serious effort  before asking, and to show us what you tried in your question.  We want to help you understand concepts, not solve your exercise for you (as that won't help you or anyone else).

Comment: @D.W. I don't believe your comment is too helpful/constructive here and now. (Yes, I am aware of the policy and the accompanied discussions).

Comment: @RanG., I confess I don't understand your meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing the comment as an answer:

Consider $L\in NPC$. By definition it means that every $A\in NP$ satisfies
$$ A\le_p NPC.$$
Similarly, if $L\in coNPC$, then by definition (which is not very common, but we can defined it in similar way to NPC), every $B \in coNP$ satisfies $$B\le_p coNPC.$$

So assume $X$ is non-empty, that is, there is $L$ which is both NP-complete, and coNP-complete.

Now, $L$ is in $NP$ (since $NPC\subseteq NP$), but it is also in $coNP$ from a similar reason. From here we will get that $NP=coNP$. Assume not, so there is a language $A\in NP$ but $A\notin coNP$ (or the other way).
But $A\le_p L$ since $L$ is complete for $NP$. This means $A$ can be reduced to a $coNP$ language (L!), which implies that $A\in coNP$, a contradiction. More generally, this reasoning implies that $NP \subseteq coNP$, and the other direction holds symmetrically. Thus $NP=coNP$ under these assumptions.